# Convertion of multiple rows being result of a subquery to string

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to convert multiple rows being result of a subquery to string in MySQL?

What I mean is the following query:

```
SELECT id, 
       FUNCTION_THAT_CONVERTS_MUTLIPLE_ROWS_TO_STRING(
          SELECT name FROM test2 t2 where t2.id = t.id
       ) FROM test t;
```

Where `SELECT name FROM test2 t2 where t2.id = t.id` returns more than one row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need to use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).